# Неправильное использование функции mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php

Всем привет

```
if (isset($_GET['text'])) {
    $text = $_GET['text'];
} else {
    $text = 0; 
}
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['$text']);
echo $text;
```

Для заноса в БД данных решил воспользоваться функцией `mysql_real_escape_string`, которая экранирует спец символы, но вместо этого данные стали пропадать. Для проверки решил написать код (указан выше), если убрать вторую строку - все работает, со второй строкой - ничего не работает.
Подскажите, что я не так сделал?

Comment: Прекратите немедленно использовать всю (прошу прошения) парашу, начинающуюся с mysql_*. Неужели Вам ничего не известно о PDO, MySqli?

По вопросу: $_REQUEST['$text']. Странная запись. Может Вы имели ввиду $_REQUEST['text'] или $_REQUEST[$text]? Уверен ошибка именно здесь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);
```

Вы бы прочитали хоть что написали. Проверяете `_GET`, юзаете `_REQUEST` (что будет при пост-запросе?), Проверяете ключ `'text'`, юзаете `'$text'`.

Answer (score 4):

Вы обращаетесь к ['$text'], а не к ['text'].
А вообще используйте [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php), так надежнее.

Comment: Вот человек истину говорит. PDO используйте. Потом (абстрактно) нам достаётся Ваш говнокод с нулевой переносимостью.
@jfk, честь тебе и хвала))